# MySQL - how to write stored procedure to insert data in to table from two other tables

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have three tables (having 4 columns each) of identical columns. First column is Unique ID which is common in all tables, other three columns in two tables have data (integer) of two months.

I want to insert difference of values present in each columns of two tables against each Unique ID in third table.

Please help me to create a procedure in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not clear why you would need a stored procedure for this.

```
insert into table1 (id,col1,col2,col3)
select t2.id,
       t2.col1-t3.col1,
       t2.col2-t3.col2,
       t2.col3-t3.col3
from table2 t2
join table3 t3 on t3.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. It's a great help. Actually I wanted to know how a procedure is written declaring various variables and storing values. The above query worked great. Thank you again.

Comment: I cannot improve on the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html. If you have any specific problems you should post what you have done and what your issue is.